# can google analytics tell me http referrer for each specific goal conversion?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, http-referer

I have a website that allows people to create an account (that is the conversion I wish to track).

I wish to know where a specific person is coming from.  I have google analytics installed and have set up the registration page as a goal, but the reporting tells me traffic sources as an aggregated pie chart.  It doesn't report down to the user account level to say that 'person with email xyz' came from 'facebook' for example.

What custom variables or mark up would I need to add to GA to report at that detailed level, if that is at all possible?

Otherwise, I will just have to record the first http_referer in a cookie and stick it in a database during the registration process.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I must ask you, how actionable do you think it is to look at data at that granular of a level?  Finding out what % of people who registered came from facebook or some other place is actionable, because it helps you do things like determine where to focus marketing efforts.  But individual users?  How is this actionable to you?  (hint: it's not)

However, if you are still determined to know this, you should first note that it is against Google's ToS to record personally identifiable data both directly (recording the actual value in GA) or indirectly (e.g. - recording a unique id that you can use to tie to personal info stored within your own system).  If this is something you don't want to risk, I suggest moving to another analytics tool that does not have this sort of thing in their ToS (e.g. Adobe SiteCatalyst, which costs money, or perhaps you may instead prefer to choose an "in-house" approach, like Piwik)

If you are *still* determined to follow through with this and hope not to get caught or whatever, Google Analytics doesn't record data like what info a visitor filled out in a form (like their email address) unless you populate that data in a custom field/dimension/metric/event to be sent along with the request.  Usually you would populate this on the form "thank you" page (which is usually the same page you use as your goal url or goal event if you're popping and using an event for your goal).  So you would populate the email address in one of those custom variables and then have it as a dimension to break down the http referrer by.

Comment: thanks for the info.  I just wanted to know if it was possible or not and didn't want to reinvent the wheel if it was.  Regarding actionable data, it depends.  In my case, not all users are created equal.  Some are particularly famous and have more influence than others and we are particularly interested in where they are coming from, more so than an other users.  But I think the best way is to simply ask them on the registration form.  Thanks.

Comment: I see. So when a visitor fills out your form claiming to be Michael Jackson, you're going to take it at face value instead of assume it's some kind of spammer?  In any case, if you are looking to ask them on the form and track it within your own system, it would be better to keep track of the referring URL and post it as a hidden field, since the visitor may not be inclined to fill that field out or answer truthfully.

Comment: Also, I did answer whether or not it is possible (it is). If you think it's something actionable then hey more power to you. But just throwin' it out there that I have a lot of experience with clients from mom-and-pop's to worldwide corps wanting to track this sort of thing.  Of the handful who have wanted to track it regardless of advice given..absolutely none of them have ever found it useful. But hey, you know your business better than anyone else.  Good luck!

Comment: I think I see your point.  I agree that knowing exactly where a user came from is not immediately actionable.  But it satisfies an itch.  When we see a particularly good contributor, we'd like to know his or her full narrative.  Who is they guy?  Where did they find us?  It's not quite as satisfying to look into GA and say, oh they have 30% chance of coming from tumblr and 35% of unknown... etc.  Is that 'itch' irrational if it's not actionable?  Maybe.

Comment: Oh I totally agree.. exploring the data can get really interesting, and can even lead to some insights that *are* actionable.. was just throwin' out a caution about venturing down the rabbit hole!